# Variável index do Angular

Tags: php, angularjs

Bom dia pessoal, será que alguém poderia me ajudar, eu preciso pegar o valor da variável index do angular para um pequeno bloco php, para fazer a remoção do mesmo no banco de dados.

Da forma que está eu não consigo, dá um erro no método $scope.remover

ERRO:

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var myApp = angular.module('app', []);            
            myApp.controller('alunosCad', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                    $scope.alunos = [                        
                        <?php                        
                        $alunosDataBase = DaoAluno::selectAll();                                     
                        $count = count($alunosDataBase);             
                        $i = 0;
                        foreach ($alunosDataBase as $alunosCad) {                            
                            if($i === ($count - 1)){
                                echo '{codigo: "'.$alunosCad->getId_aluno().'", nome: "'.$alunosCad->getNm_aluno().'", email: "'.$alunosCad->getMail_aluno().'"}';
                            }else{
                                echo '{codigo: "'.$alunosCad->getId_aluno().'", nome: "'.$alunosCad->getNm_aluno().'", email: "'.$alunosCad->getMail_aluno().'"},';
                            } 
                            $i+=1;
                        }           
                        ?>
                    ];                    
                    $scope.remover = function(index){
   $scope.alunos.splice(index, 1);                        
                        <?php                        
                        $index = "<script>document.write(index)</script>"; 
                        $aRemover = $alunosDataBase[$index];                        
                        DaoAluno::delete($aRemover->getId_aluno());
   ?>                        
                    };                
                }]);
        </script>
```

Comment: Cara você esta fazendo errado, não se usa código php no meio do Angular. Você vai ter que pegar os dados do banco de dados e retornar no formato JSON, geralmente essa requisição é feita por REST.

Comment: Ulisses, não poste fotos do seu código. Copie e cole o seu próprio código aqui como texto. E utilize a ferramenta do próprio StackOverflow para formatar o código.

Comment: Tudo bem.. obrigado..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara você esta fazendo errado, não se usa código php no meio do Angular. Você vai ter que pegar os dados do banco de dados e retornar no formato JSON, geralmente essa requisição é feita por REST.

Segue um exemplo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Link do exemplo [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_tables_simple)

Comment: Desculpa é meu primeiro contato com angular.. como o arquivo vai retornar alguma coisa... Não entendi bem como usar..

Comment: É assim mesmo, da uma lida nesse link http://imasters.com.br/desenvolvimento/exemplo-de-integracao-rest-entre-servidor-e-cliente/?trace=1519021197&source=single

Comment: Você esta usando qual framework php?

Comment: Usei bootstrap, em alguma pagina estou usando jquery, mas ainda não sei muito bem usar, tenho só um mês mexendo com php...

Comment: Como eu poderia referenciar este site caso ainda nao esteja hospedado por exemplo o arquivo ../_php/listalunos.php

Comment: é só colocar "_php/listalunos.php", não precisa ser o endereço do seu site  mas o do arquivo.

Comment: Seria desta Forma.. <script type="text/javascript">
            var app = angular.module('app', []);
            app.controller('alunosCad', function ($scope, $http) {
                $http.get("./_php/listalunos.php")
                        .then(function (response) {
                            $scope.alunos = response.data.records;
                        });
                $scope.remover = function (index) {
                    $scope.alunos.splice(index, 1);
                };                
            });
        </script>

Comment: Se eu quisesse remover varios com check box

Comment: Não entendi a forma que eu poderia fazer para remover diretamente no banco e na tabela com angular.

Comment: Então para remover vários é preciso fazer uma requisição por POST com o angular, ai sua página em php vai pegar os dados(no caso os ids) e remove-los